# Are there pangrams shorter than ‘the quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog’?

Tags: phrase-requests

Do you know pangrams shorter than the traditional *‘the quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog’* ?

Comment: The quick brown fox jumps over **a** lazy dog

Comment: The quick lazy dog jumps over a brown fox.

Comment: _General Reference_: Wikipedia has [a list of perfect pangrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pangrams#Perfect_pangrams_in_English_.2826_letters.29) and more. (via @hellion)

Comment: The following 14 letter words might help. They each don't use the same letter more than once: ambidextrously
benzhydroxamic
dermatoglyphic
hydromagnetics
hydropneumatic
pseudomythical
Schizotrypanum
subformatively
sulphogermanic
undiscoverably. And this one has 15 letters ... dermatoglyphics.

Answer (score 14):

[**How quickly daft jumping zebras vex.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram)

Comment: How vexingly quick daft zebras jump.

Answer (score 9):

> Jocks find quartz glyph, vex BMW.

(26 characters)

See more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pangrams#Perfect_pangrams_in_English_.2826_letters.29) on the Wikipedia page on pangrams.

Comment: Does that really make sense?

Comment: Using abbreviation of german words has to violate the spirit of the question.

Comment: Uh, unless I'm counting wrong, that's exactly 26 letters, i.e. the shortest possible pangram. Or does the 32 count spaces and commas as well?

Comment: You're right Marta. I will edit my post.

Comment: @FarmBoy: I think you can easily make the argument that BMW is as much an English word as any other car company's name.

Comment: @Kosmonaut You could make that argumant, but many would expect any proper noun to be excluded, so it wouldn't go very far.

Comment: @FarmBoy: Is there a rule against proper nouns in pangrams?

Comment: @Kosmonaut rule?  Who said anything about rules?  I've spoke of the spirit of the question, and the typical expectation of the answer.  I expect that the answer won't contain words invented by corporations.  If others expect differently, that's fine with me.

Comment: @FarmBoy: Yeesh, I'm just trying to understand why Bruno's clever answer should be a "spiritual" violation. It seems arbitrary to me.

Comment: @Kosmonaut It's typically the case that proper nouns and abbreviations are not allowed in word games like scrabble.  Arbitrary? Sure. But expected by many.

Comment: @FarmBoy: The word games that disallow proper nouns, like Scrabble and Boggle, have specific rules that state this.  Other word games, like crossword puzzles or Mad Libs, have no such restrictions. A pangram isn't even a game, it's simply a sentence containing every letter at least once.

Comment: Scrabble allows proper nouns for some time now.

Comment: If the French claim è and é (and so on) are actual letters, should French-language pangrams have to include them?

Answer (score 5):

> The five boxing wizards jump quickly.

(Also 31 characters.)

I used this panagram in an introduction to computer science class to test the students' understanding of arrays.

Answer (score 3):

> Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz

is my personal favorite, although sadly weighing in at one character more than MachineCharmer's.

Comment: Funny that the word *quartz* appears in many of these pangrams.It contains letters q and z, which are not frequent compared to most of the other letters.

Answer (score 3):

Cheating...

I tried to use the [Internet Anagram Server](http://wordsmith.org/anagram/) to find pangrams with only 26 letters, but it says the server load is too high right now, but it did offer a link to another page with only [pangrams](http://wordsmith.org/words/pangram.html).  Here is the list they provide (some already offered in other answers):

- Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs. (thirty-two letters)
- Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz. (thirty-one)
- How quickly daft jumping zebras vex. (thirty)
- Quick wafting zephyrs vex bold Jim. (twenty-nine)
- Waltz, nymph, for quick jigs vex Bud. (twenty-eight)
- Bawds jog, flick quartz, vex nymph. (twenty-seven)
- Mr. Jock, TV quiz Ph.D., bags few lynx. (twenty-six!)

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly, the shortest was a newspaper headline about some vandals who wanted to carve something into a quartz column, only to find it had already been vandalized:
"Quartz glyph job vex'd cwm finks" - 26 letters, + apostrophe.

I'm not sure how the cwm (coom) works into it, unless there was a valley involved.

Comment: They need glasses: o͞o

Comment: Vandals from a Welsh valley.