# Is there a sentence containing every letter without repeating?

Tags: sentence, alphabet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shortest pangram](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16654/shortest-pangram)

Does anyone know of a coherent sentence that contains every letter in the alphabet without repeating any?

Comment: Is this a duplicate? This questions seems more about avoiding repetitions instead of including every character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page suggests no: http://www.rinkworks.com/words/pangrams.shtml, unless you want to include acronyms and the like.

> Constructing a sentence that uses every letter of the alphabet once and no more -- essentially an anagram of the alphabet -- seems to require the use of acronyms, initials, and strange punctuation. The most interesting I've seen is, "Glum Schwartzkopf vex'd by NJ IQ."