# Phrases with as many different letters as possible

Tags: single-word-requests

I remember there was a term for such sentences. Does anyone know what they are called?

Comment: Related: [Shortest pangram](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16654/shortest-pangram)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Pangram" is pretty close and may be the word you were thinking of:

> A pangram (Greek: pan gramma, "every letter"), or holoalphabetic sentence, is a sentence using every letter of the alphabet at least once. ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram))

If you are curious about short pangrams, [we have some answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16654/shortest-pangram) for that, too!